# Annotations through Applications in Seam

Tags: java, jboss, seam

I want to split up my project in diffrent modules so i can just swap them out if needed. Atm i just Jboss Developer Studio.

So i want my templates , login etc to be in 1 module/Application

Then i want to be able to access thease annotations and beans in another application.

Is this possible to do ?

Or is this seperation of modules possible todo within 1 application, so it is easy to extract all the xhtml,java files,navigation rules that are assoisiated with one module?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the same question with only servlet API. As JSF is just a servlet and Seam is just filters and services for JSF. If you get to know the low level details, you may have success in any framework, including seam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize all your java classes/annotations/interfaces into separate jars. Just ensure that there is a seam.properties file in the META-INF folder. When seam starts up, it scans all jars in the classpath to see if they have that file. If so, it adds them as possible components. So you can just include these various jars in your war.

I've never found a way to include xhtml files from separate wars/jars and have them actually function in a war. We currently use the overlay feature of maven to combine various wars into a big one. It combines the various faces-config, components.xml and xhtml files into one large war that we deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly re-use the back end beans and assemble them in components.xml in new apps, just by referencing a separate JAR containing the classes. Front end resources - not so sure.